# Replace missing values with previous values in Julia Data Frame

Tags: julia

Imagine I have a data frame like below:

[image]

What I want to do is to fill those missing values with previous values, so after fillling the data frame would be like:

[image]

Is there any simple way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it using Impute.jl:

```
julia> using Impute, DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(dt1=[0.2, missing, missing, 1, missing, 5, 6],
                      dt2=[0.3, missing, missing, 3, missing, 5, 6])
7×2 DataFrame
 Row │ dt1        dt2
     │ Float64?   Float64?
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │       0.2        0.3
   2 │ missing    missing
   3 │ missing    missing
   4 │       1.0        3.0
   5 │ missing    missing
   6 │       5.0        5.0
   7 │       6.0        6.0

julia> transform(df, names(df) .=> Impute.locf, renamecols=false)
7×2 DataFrame
 Row │ dt1       dt2
     │ Float64?  Float64?
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │      0.2       0.3
   2 │      0.2       0.3
   3 │      0.2       0.3
   4 │      1.0       3.0
   5 │      1.0       3.0
   6 │      5.0       5.0
   7 │      6.0       6.0
```

Comment: Hi, This method works except that the argument 'renamecols' is not supported in my package version. What is your package version? And is there any other way to replace this argument? Or maybe I need to run it without the argument and drop the original columns instead.

Comment: Please update DataFrams.jl to 0.22 version. On older versions `transform(df, names(df) .=> Impute.locf .=> names(df))` should work (depending on how old your DataFrames.jl version is).

Comment: Thank you, the other method works on my Julia :)

Comment: `mapcols(df, Impute.locf)` should be equivalent and a bit shorter.

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat The function goes first: `mapcols(Impute.locf, df)`

Answer (score 1):

Using a quick for loop would do the trick. Maybe it is useful to wrap into a function

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(a = [1, missing, 2], b = [3, missing, 4])

previous = 0
for c in 1:ncol(df), r in 1:nrow(df)
    if !ismissing(df[r, c])
        previous = df[r,c]
    else
        df[r,c] = previous
    end
end

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a      │ b      │
│     │ Int64? │ Int64? │
├─────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 3      │
│ 2   │ 1      │ 3      │
│ 3   │ 2      │ 4      │
```

Comment: You would have to add a special case to your code if the some column contains `missing` in the first row.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That might in fact be a benefit of this method as it leaves the user the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = DataFrame(dt1=[missing, 0.2, missing, missing, 1, missing, 5, 6],
                      dt2=[9, 0.3, missing, missing, 3, missing, 5, 6])

filldown(v)=accumulate((x,y)->coalesce(y,x), v,init=v[1])

transform(df,[:dt1,:dt2].=>filldown,renamecols=false)


julia> transform(df,[:dt1,:dt2].=>filldown,renamecols=false) 
8×2 DataFrame
 Row │ dt1        dt2     
     │ Float64?   Float64 
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ missing        9.0
   2 │       0.2      0.3
   3 │       0.2      0.3
   4 │       0.2      0.3
   5 │       1.0      3.0
   6 │       1.0      3.0
   7 │       5.0      5.0
   8 │       6.0      6.0
```

```
fillup(v)=reverse(filldown(reverse(v)))

transform(df,[:dt2,:dt1].=>[filldown,fillup],renamecols=false)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).